# Did Turkish people commit 70–80% of the rapes in Cologne around the year 1996?

Tags: criminology, sexual-abuse, germany

In an [interview by the *Kölner Stadt-Anzeiger* from 2016-12-29](http://www.ksta.de/koeln/silvesternacht-am-dom-koelner-polizeichef-wuenscht-sich-boeller-verbot-25386236-seite2), the journalist/feminist [Alice Schwarzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Schwarzer) said (in German):

> Dass vor 20 Jahren 70 bis 80 Prozent aller Vergewaltigungen in Köln von Türken begangen wurden, war der Polizei wohlbekannt.

My translation:

> It was well-known by the police that, 20 years ago, 70–80% of all rapes in Cologne were committed by Turkish people.

Let’s leave aside if it was well-known by the police, and let’s assume that "20 years ago" is a ballpark estimate (so maybe a year between 1993 and 1999, or whatever seems sensible), is it true?

Comment: Schwarzer made a similar claim in 2003 on her website ([aliceschwarzer.de, archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20110128055322/http://www.aliceschwarzer.de/zur-person/texte-ueber-alice/2003/ich-bin-es-leid-eine-frau-zu-sein-41203/)). Back then her source wasn't "the police", but one specific - but unnamed - policeman. Neither her nor any of the right-wing websites citing this figure seem to have bothered to actually look up the statistics or verify this with the police department in the last 20 years. I wasn't able to find any official source using this figure.

Comment: I doubt that any available data can confirm or reject the claim. A significant part of the residents of Turkish origin are German citizens and therefore not counted as foreigners in the public crime statistics.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: They weren't German 20 years ago.

Comment: Alice Schwarzer is *not* a reliable source.

Comment: @MartinSchröder which is why this question is being asked. If she were a reliable source, we probably wouldn't have this question.